# Distribute work between Hadoop nodes

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a Hadoop cluster including 1 NameNode and 3 dataNodes.

In order to process a search operation on one CSV file, I cut my CSV file in 3 files.
So, I set Input Path to my folder containing my 3 CSV files in order to use my 3 nodes to process map operation on these files.

It seems to work fine but there is no time saving compared to process map operation on 1 big CSV file...

I have 1 NameNode (4 vCpu Xeon @ 2.8Ghz, 6GO RAM) and 3 Datanodes (2vCpu Xeon @ 2.8Ghz, 4GO RAM), and map operation takes around 7 seconds to parse my CSV file which contains ~500,000 lines (300Mb).

Here is my Map class: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jorisbertomeu/df105d75c2e3712c5119c10eceff4424)

Thank you!

Comment: what is the size of your original file and what is the block size of your cluster ?

Comment: you don't need to cut the file. based on the block size your cluster will distribute it in blocks ?

Comment: The size of my original file is 300Mb. and the block size of my cluster is 128Mb.

Comment: Yes, my cluster will distribute my file in blocks but I think that all my nodes are not working when I process map operation ..

Comment: If I shut down 2/3 nodes, map operation takes same time that if there are 3/3 nodes ..

Comment: when you shut down 2 nodes all block gets replicated in single node and data processing will take place on single node only therefore it is taking time.

Comment: when I shut down my 2 nodes, map process takes 7 seconds and when my 2 nodes are up, map process takes 7 seconds as well .. :(

Comment: Can you initiate a chat session where we can discuss it  ?

Comment: I would really like it but my reputation is too low .. I you're available, in 1h30, I would really appreciate chat with you in order to help me! Maybe do you have another solution for chat ? Thank you :)

Comment: I an suggest you to check logs to find out how many splits  are getting created for your job. You can also check mappers and reducer assigned for the job.

Comment: Its is also recommended to add log in your question so that  other can check and suggests.